# Post-Build powershell - help getting syntax (spaces help)

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, variables, post-build-event

Running a post-build powershell command and my path has spaces as does the two args I'm trying to pass.  I have no idea how to get this to work.  One of the issues is a fun little double-quote that is showing up.  Ultimately the following is what I'm looking for........

```
powershell -file "$(ProjectDir)PS\upgradeApp.ps1" -projDir "$(ProjectDir)" -targetDir "$(TargetDir)"
```

Note -- projDir has spaces as does targetDir.  Fine, let's just get the first arg....

```
powershell -file "$(ProjectDir)PS\upgradeApp.ps1" -projDir "$(ProjectDir)"
```

What happens then is I'm mysteriously left with a trailing double-quote for the projectDir arg.  Why?

```
C:\Users\user.domain\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WikiAdditions\WikiAdditions"
```

I've tried putting in single quotes, then double-quotes but then I get a trailing single quote.  So what's the magic formula here?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out........... thanks for the headache Powershell, because that looks logical.

```
powershell.exe –command "& { &'$(ProjectDir)PS\upgradeApp.ps1' '$(ProjectDir)' '$(TargetDir)' }"
```

Comment: Far out you just saved me! I spent hours on this - HOW DOES THAT MAKE ANY SENSE?!